# Proper way to say "Grocery store​" and what types of stores this usage applies to

Tags: word-choice, words, nuances, word-usage

What is the proper way? According to [jisho](https://jisho.org/search/grocery%20store), it seems as simple as saying  食{しょく}品{ひん}店{てん}? In the case of a Walmart, Target, <s>GameStop</s> Costco or Family Dollar could these all be considered 食{しょく}品{ひん}店{てん}?.

I know some stores are referred to as Konbini as well, but those stores are smaller in size as, like 7-Eleven. I am wondering if there are any other spoken words that used to refer to stores of various sizes as well.

Comment: I may be looking at a wrong one, but does GameStop count as a grocery store? https://www.gamestop.com/deals

Comment: GameStop sells food now?

Comment: 私はです。maybe energy drinks and candy, but you both are correct i should replace that example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Grocery store" in Englsh may refer to different things.

> #### [Grocery store](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grocery_store)
>
> A grocery store (AE), grocery shop (BE) or simply grocery is a store that primarily retails a general range of food products, which may be fresh or packaged. **In everyday U.S. usage, however, "grocery store" is a synonym for supermarket,** and is not used to refer to other types of stores that sell groceries.

> The definition of "grocery store" varies...

If "grocery store" refers to supermarkets, the equivalent term in Japanese is スーパーマーケット or スーパー for short. Most スーパー in Japan also sell toothbrushes, detergents and such, but there are smaller スーパー that almost exclusively sell food (sometimes specifically called 食品スーパー). A large Walmart seems to sell even TVs and vacuum cleaners, but Japanese supermarkets don't sell such items.

食料品店 is a general term for stores that sell food to take home, and this may be closer to the "original" meaning of groceries. However, it is not a term commonly used in everyday life. Perhaps it refers primarily to small specialized stores such as bakeries, coffee bean stores, etc.

There are also コンビニ (convenience stores) and [ドラッグストア](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/96741/5010) (drugstores) in Japan. These are almost the same as their English equivalents.

Comment: @greg -- To add to naruto's answer, there's also the older English term [_greengrocer_](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/greengrocer), referring to a shop that sells produce, but not other items.  This seems to equate to the Japanese term [八百屋](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%E5%85%AB%E7%99%BE%E5%B1%8B).

Comment: thanks for the inputs @Eiríkr Útlendi!

Comment: @naruto would you say that スーパー is used more commonly than 食料品店?

Comment: @greg Any kindergartener can use スーパー, while adults use 食料品店 less than once a year.

Comment: @naruto which term do adults use more commonly? スーパーマーケット?